# Get values from an auto-generated table (generated by dhtmlxgrid) and set it to a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

EDIT: Ok, i found a way to get the cell-content and make a javascript variable (via dhtmlxgrid functions, something like var `leadID = mygrid.cells(id,1).getValue();)`.

Now the remaining question is how i can get this javascript variable to be available in php for my sql query. On first pageload, since one of the table-cells should display the amount of comments made for this customer.

I need a query like (query is made on first pageload, to feed a cell with data)

```
$query_entryNo = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from comment WHERE post_id = $leadID ");
```

Where `$leadID` is the UserID you see in column 2 on screenshot.

End Edit

### probably can ignore the text below...

Hello, i have something i dont know the answer and cannot find a way to do it.

Some info first:

I have an autogenerated table that is build with the help of dhtmlxgrid plugin (javascript). The table that is generated has no class or ID, also not the cells themself and i dont want to mess around with the plugin-sourcecode, for various reasons. So the table will stay class- and id-less.

Every row in this auto-generated table displays a user with his userID, name, email and all that.

I need to fetch  this userid for an sql query. I would need this already on first pageload, not after some post or something like that. One column will contain the amount of comments that one made for this user and this i do with sql/php, soo i need some way to get the right db-entry. Comments are linked to the userid, thats why i need the id to be included in the php code for sql-query.

How can i achieve this? Basically the question is how i can get the id shown in column 2 into an sql query.

The screenshot shows the ID in the table that i somehow have to have in my sql query.

Since this table is generated through javascript and the comments are stored in another table i cannot use the basic dhtmlxgrid functions to do this. I have to build around my own way.

[image: Auto-generated table]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking and probably too broad. It sounds like you don't understand the tools you are trying to use. Maybe I am just not understanding though.

Comment: i changed it. Maybe its more clear now. English isnt my main-language, sorry. I not ask about dhtmlxgrid or something, just how i can parse the cell of this autogenerated table for the userID that is displayed in column 2 (see screen). THis userID i need to use in an sql query

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong: You are trying to fill a SQL Query issued from PHP at site creation from a Javascript variable assigned at site load?

Comment: yep, sounds right :-) the table is created at pageload of course, from javascript. Same time (after table is created) i create a variable that gets its data from the table cell. Now i need this variable available in php, basically also at pageload because one of the cells has to display data i get from an sql query.

I found things like do this with an ajax post but i fail.

Comment: Okay a Design like this is usually fundamently flawed. Where does JS get its data from? Is it in any way generated by PHP, and then processed by Javascript and should be returned to PHP? Why not do the processing in PHP?

Comment: @JohannesWalcher they use a javascript plugin to generate the table. Yes, it gets the data from a db but from a different table. ANd the plugin as it is doesnt allow to fill one cell with data from another table by default.

Its built like this:

`$grid = new GridConnector($conn,"MySQL");
 $grid->render_table("Customers","ID","Agent,ID,Favourite,FirstName,Phone,Email,Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4,SalesStage,LeadCreated,OfferSent,OfferOpened,Comment", "ID");`

No way to tell it should use another db. I have to hardcode it myself i think.

Comment: But i have the option to hardcode a jquery function to attach any html to a cell after its generated. I use this way now to fill the data with dynamic links based on userID. But al is jqery, so i have to pass the php variable to javascript somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our Discussion in the comments I can give you this Solution:

1. Send Data from PHP to Javasript (at Site-Creation time on Server side): just add a `echo "<script>var data=$data; </script>"`, if it is more complicated you have to convert it into JSON (google that).
2. To send data on-the fly from Javascript to PHP you need a PHP-side recieving page, that reads your POST-Data. To send the request just use [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) like this:

   ```
   $.post("http://example.com/ajax.php", data);
   ```

   This will send an asynchronous call to your server.

So in your case, you read the values from the table via Javascript, save them into an array, and prepare the data that it will be interpreted the right way by PHP-Post mechanism:

```
ajaxData = ""; 
for (int i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    ajaxData += "data[" + i + "]=" + tableData[i] + "&"; 
}
$.post("ajax.php", data); //This will take the relative path to your site
```

You see, that POST data has to be encoded the same way as GET-data.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Probably right but i cant implement it atm. Too much trouble with this grid functions. As soon as i try it i accept as right answer. Sorry :-(